Command 'flet' not found in ubuntu
Iam install flet in my Ubuntu 20.4 by command
pip3 install flet

I can see that flet is installed
pip3 list

But when i type flet in CLI, I got an error
Command 'flet' not found

You need to add ~/.local/bin to your PATH. In your home directory, open .bash_aliases with a text editor and add the line
export PATH=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.local/bin:$PATH

replacing YOUR_USERNAME with your actual username. Save it, open a new terminal window and you should be good to go
